# Getting cmd: Failure calling service activity: Failed transaction (2147483646) when trying to debug on emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio, emulation

Started getting this error all of a sudden for my Flutter project
Clearing cache did not help.
Rebooting did not help

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me is closing the emulator and cold-booting it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Here's what worked for me:

1. Navigate to AVD folders in file explorer (for me it was ursnm/.android./avd)
2. Select and delete all files in here,
3. From Android Studio, go to AVD Manager (should be empty now) and create a new device.

I am very novice, so I have no idea why this worked, but it did for me.

-Brian